# GUI locks uo, when running a thread in event, why

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I need to be enable to hit cancel or stop button on my gui.
But my gui locks when I run the event. And I can see why ?

so I start a new thread, witch run the loop, checking to se if I have hit cancel.
Inside the loop, I start a new thread for handle the job, and after that, updates the gui.

```
   //this is button click event.

    filesToImport = [list of obj, with information abount som task that needs to be done]
        TaskScheduler taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(); // current gui context 

    // start a new thread
              Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                foreach (fics_ds_import job in filesToImport)
                {
    // have the user cancel();

                  if (this.CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                  {
                    //this.CancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    break;
                  }

// start new thread for doing the task, and update the gui.
                  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.DoSomeWork(this.ConnectionStringTxt.Text, job), this.CancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler).ContinueWith(o => this.UpdateProcessStatus(), taskScheduler);
                }
              }, this.CancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, taskScheduler);
```

Comment: You specifically ask for the task to run on the UI thread.  So sure, it locks up until the task is complete.

Comment: But if I cant, set the UI thread. How do I construct the code, to do the work and update the GUI ?

Comment: @HansPassant THX, I change the outer thread to use TaskScheduler.Default so I only locks the ui thread, when I update the gui. Is there a better way ?

Comment: @HansPassant Is it possible for you to add and Answer, so I can close this thread.